# Why do operation on <bit> return signed numbers?

Tags: c++, c++20, bit

Operations like

```
template< class T >
constexpr int popcount( T x ) noexcept;
```

return a signed integer, but the number of set bits can never be negative? What was the motivation for choosing a signed rather than unsigned type?

Comment: What use would there be for `unsigned`? The function will never return values anywhere near 2^31.

Comment: And unlikely even in the worst case of 16 bit int.

Comment: Using `unsigned` numbers is a bit more prone to some errors like 2u - 3u would result in a large positive number.

Comment: @Sneftel So many bit sets are unsigned but the operations on them always make the number signed. Which is annoying. So I think there is more motivation for preserving the type of the arguments.

Comment: @Mikhail popcount isn't like xor. The output is not the same "sort of thing" as the input. Consider if there was a `popcount(float)` which counted the number of bits in the representation of the given floating-point number; would you want that to return a `float`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [the paper](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p0553r4.html):

> The counting operations return "int" quantities, consistent with the rule "use an int unless you need something else". This choice does not reflect, in the type, the fact that counts are always non-negative.

gcc's intrinsic here (`__builtin_popcount`) also returns `int`.

Comment: support of the answer does not signify an endorsement of P0553R4 :-)

Comment: not worth the separate answer, but it is not just WG21, google style guide also has same guideline. "You should not use the unsigned integer types such as uint32_t, unless there is a valid reason such as representing a bit pattern rather than a number, or you need defined overflow modulo 2^N. In particular, do not use unsigned types to say a number will never be negative. Instead, use assertions for this."(obviously assertions are useless in <bit> since HW logic is assumed to be correct)

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl part of my job is interviewing refugees from Google's style guide. The function actually is specialized so that it takes unsigned number but makes them signed.